# Adjective + とする

Tags: adjectives

From [英語子音の攻略](https://www.cais.or.jp/station/10/007.html)

> 次回は、これらの日本人にとって**苦手とする**発音をどのように訓練するのかということについて、ご紹介していきます。

My dictionary defines とする as:

> そのように仮定する意を表す。

Does this definition apply to the sentence that I've found?
Is the nuance in this context something along the lines of, "You think you're bad at it, but you don't have to be"?

Comment: 苦手とする発音=difficult to pronounce.  or more literally "sounds they're not skilled in making"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this とする simply means "to regard". It's the second definition in [this entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/159047/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/):

> １ …と仮定する。「ここに川があるとする」
>   ２ …と考える。…と判断する。「彼の意見をよしとする者」

So 日本人にとって苦手とする発音 means "the pronunciation which Japanese people regard as difficult."

But I feel this phrase is slightly clumsy. 日本人にとって苦手な発音 (using a na-adjective) or 日本人が苦手とする発音 (using a relative clause with a subject and a verb) would be better.