# とし in this sentence, among other problems

Tags: translation, meaning, song-lyrics

I was trying to translate this song (full lyrics here: http://vocadb.net/S/87131 )
and I'm having a lot of trouble with these two lines:

> 混沌に鎖されし　喪服纏った我を　蝕む右手の薔薇
>   宿命とし　後罪滲む

"Trapped by the chaos, having put on my mourning clothes, a rose in my worm-eaten right hand, I make a decision to blot out my crime (btw 後罪 is pronounced クライム)" is what I could figure out. Mostly I'm confused about とし here. I would think it's a continuative of とする, but the only uses I could find with とする are the typical を~とする and volitional + とする, which doesn't seem to apply here. And I'm not sure if 宿命 (which is pronounced 定め) should even be "decision" or "fate." Literally I could only translate the last line based on context also; as you can see, I'm very confused!

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's the continuative form of とする, and I think it's "typical を～とする" you already know, with を omitted because it's already mentioned in the previous sentence(?). It just means "consider something ～" or "regard something as ～".

定め【さだめ】 can mean the same thing as 運命, doom, fate, etc.

So "regarding it (=薔薇) as my(?) fate, ..."

See:

- [Adjective + とする](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44656/5010)
- [what is the meaning of a た形の動詞　＋　とする](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47030/5010)

Comment: Oh, okay, so 蝕む右手の薔薇 goes with 宿命とし, and 後罪滲む, then, is just by itself? ("Trapped by the chaos, having put on my mourning clothes, I regard the worm-eaten rose in the right hand as my fate; my crime is blurred.")