# Meaning of とし in this sentence

Tags: meaning, particle-と

> Aが出たとし、B。 (This is what the speaker is telling to another person on the phone)

Where A is an event that already happend (let's say an accident), and B means something like "I'll send you more info on that"

is とし the continuative form of とする, or is it と + し. Also I found this: [what is the meaning of a た形の動詞　＋　とする](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47030/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-%E3%81%9F%E5%BD%A2%E3%81%AE%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E-%EF%BC%8B-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)  but I'm don't know how to apply that to my sentence

Comment: What do you mean by "と + し"? I can think of only one possible interpretation, but it's usually a fairly literary expression that's rarely used over the phone. Could you share the full sentence?

Comment: that とし part is not part of what the speaker is saying over the phone. It was added as part of the indirect speech

Comment: とする has many meanings and it's very hard to answer this if you keep hiding the remaining parts of the sentence. But if you're sure `Aが出た` is part of an indirect speech, [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44656/5010) may be related.