# NounをAdjectiveとするNoun meaning something like a normal adjective

Tags: grammar, particle-と

This is a bit embarrassing, but on no less than the very first line of Komi-san, in Japanese, I'm presented with the following:

[image]

Now I've searched for a solid hour and found no definition for NounをAdjectiveとするNoun that makes sense in this context. Specifically:

> 人付き合いを苦手とする症状

DeepL gives something along the lines of "The symptoms of bad social disposition".

The English translation gives something like "it's a condition where a person has trouble communicating with other people"

I'm now unsure if the first big line is crucial here. I'm just kind of stumped as to how this grammar works.

Comment: Does it help? [Meaning of ~を~に(して) / ~を~として / ~を~にする / ~を~とする / ~を~にした / ~を~とした](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73082/)

Comment: I think this is either another usage, or I just don't get it: this talks about "use something as something", but applying that here gets us "using social skills as bad" which just sounds odd

Comment: Using one-on-one English translation to understand each word is bad. 苦手 has another meaning, look up!

Comment: I mean I can rephrase to "using social skills as bad at (social skills)" but I don't really think that's helping understanding

Comment: Hmm, this phrase difficult to translate naturally... how about "condition when one considers socializing as something they are bad at"

Comment: That's interesting... I'm still not sure if I'm missing something but that feels like a better translation

Comment: Another related：https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44656/45489

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「AをBとする」 can mean not only "to regard A as B", "to use A as B", but also "to have A as B", or even "(Speaking of the subject,) A is B."

> マリア**を**母**とし**、... (≈マリアが母で...)
> 日本語**を**母語**と**し、... (≈日本語が母語で...)
> 先天性心疾患治療**を**得意**と**します。 (≈先天性心疾患治療が得意です。)

I think this usage sounds pretty literary. (These examples above sound more literary than the rephrased counterparts in the brackets.)

---

And 「AをBとするXX」 can mean "XX having A as B", "XX with A being B", or "XX, where A is B" (≈「AがBであるXX」「AがBのXX」), as in...

> - 「遺伝子組換えでない食品を原材料とする場合」 (≈遺伝子組換えでない食品が原材料である場合), "a case where 遺伝子組み換えでない食品 is (a product's) ingredient"
> - 「日向灘を震源とする地震」 (≈日向灘が震源である地震), "an earthquake with 日向灘 being its 震源"
> - 「中学生を対象とするコンクール」 (≈中学生が対象のコンクール), "a competition where 中学生 are its 対象"
> - 「日本語を母語とする者」 (≈日本語が母語である者) "someone having Japanese as their native language" ⇒ "someone whose native language is Japanese"

Similar examples:

> - 「治療を目的とする手術」 (≈治療が目的である手術)
> - 「ストーブを原因とする火災」 (≈ストーブが原因の火災)
> - 「外科を専門とする医師」 (≈外科が専門の医師)
> - 「英語を不得意とする学生」 (≈英語が不得意な学生)

Similarly...

> 「人付き合い**を**苦手**とする**症状」≈「人付き合いが苦手である症状」

I think it can be understood as (*literally*) "a symptom where socialising is one's weakness", ⇒ "A symptom where one is bad at socialising".

Comment: Thanks so much! And just to clarify, these usages of とする sound pretty literary, is that right?

Comment: @Riolku Yeah, they sound pretty literary/formal. The examples I gave above (eg 英語を不得意とする学生) sound more literary/formal than the rephrased counterparts (eg 英語が不得意な学生).